# get both iBeacon & Eddystone beacon data in one scanning using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, eddystone

I need help to find iBeacon & Eddystone both in one scan method. As I tried so many examples but I didn't found example, which can fetch both iBeacon & Eddystone in same method. If anyone know the answer for my question then please help me to solve this issue.

I don't want peripheral scan.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot scan for both iBeacon and Eddystone frames with a single API.  Why?  Because Apple blocks this by design.

- iBeacon can only be detected using the CoreLocation API `startRangingBeacons(region: region)`.  Apple blocks detecting its frames using CoreBluetooth APIs.
- Eddystone frames can only be detected using CoreBluetooth APIs.  There is no support in CoreLocation, as it was invented by Google and not natively supported by Apple.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :)
Yes, I know. I tried with beacon's byte code too but not worked. I thought someone definitely got solution for this issue :( .